# What is the fastest Minecraft launcher for versions 1.17 or 1.16.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance, minecraft-launcher

Which Minecraft launcher gives the best performance in lower end computers? My specs are as follows (*I know pretty old...*):

- 3.7 GiB Ram
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz (1 physical processor; 2 cores; 4 threads)
- Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) Fully-Upgraded OS
- Intel® HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2) Graphics Card
- OpenGL 3.0
- Dell Latitude E5530 with UEFI boot
- openjdk-16-jre (removed jdk cause )

The proposed launcher ***must*** work with Java edition `1.16.5` at a minimum, though I'm looking for `1.17`.

Comment: You say you have 3.7 GiB of RAM but the Minimum Requirements for Ubuntu is 4 GiB of RAM.

Comment: Yeah! But it still runs smooth and I don't have any applications that I don't use often.It was 18 and I upgraded it to 20 thats all.

Answer (score 3):

The default launcher should be fine. Launchers do not really impact your performance. Also, I am warning you that your computer is below the minimum system requirements for Minecraft so you may have issues running the game.

Comment: I heard that some do: like Curseforge and most say multimc is fast. BUT I wanna know if I use gdlauncher will it make any impact in performance?. Does it support 1.17?

Comment: MultiMC would definitely be faster than the stock launcher, since it uses the performance-oriented Qt UI framework. Not sure what the stock launcher uses, but it looks to be web-based, which has a memory overhead